# Automatic welding in blender

Tags: mesh, edges

I'm a newbie here trying to rig a character that was made with a3d scanner- 
the rigging went relatively well but it seems that once I test my character using the rig it breaks in certain places, looks like there are cracks in the model, I saw that different 3d editing apps have automatic tools to find and fix these by welding edges, is there a way to do this the automatically in blender?

thanks !

Comment: If it's a case of duplicated, overlapping vertices, you could try `Remove Doubles`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a separate procedure that needs to be done after rigging the model known as '[Weight Painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/index.html)'.

More info here:
https://youtu.be/vMGTQFOgV_0
https://youtu.be/mhQY2_gVoVg

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It's not that, when I fixed the model in another 3d program it wasn't getting cracked even with average weights that distorted it in a bad looking way, it was called something like edge welding or something like that.

Comment: Can you please post an image or a gif of your problem? Also, the question title seems a bit inappropriate. You can change it to 'distorted mesh' or something like that and you can change the tags to modelling, rigging, weight painting etc.. In this way, you would get more and better answers.